# Derivates being bounded in some subinterval

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f(x)$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$. Prove that there exists a subinterval $(c,d)\subset(a,b)$ such that $f'(x)$ is bounded on $(c,d)$.

I have no idea then.

Comment: Derivatives are Baire class one functions; that is, the pointwise limit of continuous functions (difference quotients in this case). Such functions, defined on an interval, are continuous on a dense subset of their domain. Your result follows from this.

Comment: I think the [proof of the aforementioned fact](http://books.google.com/books?id=4VFDVy1NFiAC&pg=PA183&lpg=PA183&dq=pointwise+limit+continuous+functions+bounded+on+some+interval&source=bl&ots=l8aRgkUp6k&sig=20-03RhWMd0ajJbNwNoJvfHza-o&hl=en&sa=X&ei=P0CzUYHtDubW0QGkj4CADg&ved=0CCkQ6AEwADgU#v=onepage&q=pointwise%20limit%20continuous%20functions%20bounded%20on%20some%20interval&f=false) can be modified to prove your result directly.

Answer (score 3):

Modifying the Carother's proof mentioned in my comment above:

For each positive integer $n$, define $f_n(x)={f(x+1/n)-f(x)\over 1/n}$. Then $(f_n)$ converges to $f'$ pointwise on $(a,b)$.

Now, for $n$ a positive integer, define the set $E_n=\cap_{i,j\ge n}\{ x : |f_i(x)-f_j(x)|\le 1\}$. By the pointwise convergence of $(f_n)$, it follows that $\cup_{i=1}^\infty E_i=(a,b)$. Also, since each $f_i$ is continuous, each $E_n$ is closed.

From the Baire Category Theorem (or rather, the corollary that an open interval is not a countable union of nowhere dense sets)  it follows that there is an $n$ and an open interval $I $ which is a proper subset of $(a,b)$ such that $I\subset E_n$. From the definition of $E_n$, it follows that for all $x\in I$ and all $i,j\ge n$, we have $|f_i(x)-f_j(x)|\le 1$. Consequently, for all $x\in I$, we have $|f'(x)-f_n(x)|\le 1$.

Now, as $f_n$ is continuous on $I$, it follows that there is an $M$ so that $|f_n(x)|\le M$ for all $x\in I$.  But then for all $x\in I$, we have $|f'(x)|\le M+1$, which proves the result.

Comment: Nice answer, +1. In some cases, we could even find $I=(a,b)$, so there is no real reason to take $I$ to be a "proper" subset. It is adding an extra tiny step which is not needed anyway.

Comment: @julien Thanks. I, perhaps inelegantly, added "proper subset"  so that the first sentence of the last paragraph would be true. Can this be avoided? I can't help but wonder if there is a simpler proof; I did not use any property of derivatives other than the fact that they are Baire Class One.